How to add event listener when the bootstrap modal is shown
<button type="button" class="btn main-button btn-tableColumns add-campaign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_campaign">{{__('Add New Campaign')}}</button>

I have above code to show add_campaign modal
$("#add_campaign").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  console.log("form is showing");
  $("#add_campaign_url_error").css("display", "none");
});

I used this code to add some event listener when the modal is shown
But it isn't fired
I was trying to use different events
